# Sharing personal folders between windows and linux

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, user-accounts, personal-data

There are Music, Downloads and some other folders in the home directory of a user which can be opened from the side pane in file manager.

I want them to point to directories in some other drive so that I can share these folders among different operating systems. How can I achieve that?

Deleting those folders and making shortcuts doesn't work because in windows the type of a file is determined from it's extension and the shortcut is named with a `.lnk` extension. The file manager looks for a `directory` named `Music` when I click on Music in the side pane. If I remove the extension then the file isn't recognized anymore as a known filetype.

How can I share personal folders between windows and linux?

Moving these folders to C: drive and making shortcuts on linux isn't what I want because I'll have to backup these folders in case something happens to the windows installation. I intend to keep these personal folders separate from the installation of both OS's.

Answer (score 1):

your now state is not clear.
however:

- if both Windows and Linux turn on at the same time in different machines, then you need a network between them and setup folder sharing like Samba on Linux.
- if both on the same machine, so you use virtualization like *kvm* or *sun virtual box*, so you need a type of network that allows guest machines to find each other and setup folder sharing as above.
- if both on the same machine as multiple boots (that I guessed this is your state), you first need to find the *Partition Name* which your intended folder in it(you could find in manage window), then mount it in Linux with  `mount` command.

according to your comment:

- find your partition name:

  1. Click on Start. On for example windows 8, right-click on the bottom-left corner of the screen.
  2. Right-click on Computer. On Windows 8, instead click on Disk Management.
  3. Left-click on Manage to bring up the Windows Computer Management interface.
  4. In the left window, under Storage, click on Disk Management.
     then according *Windows drive name* and *Partition Names* which list in above Window could find the *expected Partition Name*.
- in Linux:

  1. with `fdisk -l` find mentioned partition to be sure you are right.(assume it is /dev/sd1)
  2. with `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media` command it mount in /media path.

P.S.
depending on your OS type and drive partition you may need install some extra package on Linux like *ntfs* package.
I hope it is useful.

Comment: I've dual booted windows and linux and have my personal folders on a separate partition. What I need is a way to link them to my home directory in windows installation.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a dual-boot system, you need a partition that can be read and written from both Windows and Linux. Windows doesn't understand the ext-family of filesystems, so the only choice is a FAT partition.

So on Windows, this FAT partition will be a different drive (say, E:). On Linux, you'll make mount point for it somewhere and mount it there (say, `/mnt/shared`).

The home directory on both OS will be an a different partition (NTFS for Windows, ext4 or btrfs for Linux). On Linux, you can just make symlinks from the home directory with `ln -s`, so something like

```
ln -s /mnt/shared/Music /home/saga/Music
```

On Windows, I don't see a reason why `.lnk` shortcut to a `E:` shouldn't work - you don't have to rename them (they are not used by Linux), just leave the names as they are. Should they not work, then Windows NTFS also has "real" links (not desktop links) which you can make with [mklnk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mklink) from the command line (and possibly also with a filemanager somehow, google).